# Page navigation stopped working after updating Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I added a page navigation to a clients website a while ago using the code:

```
<?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>
    <nav id="nav-posts">
        <?php
        global $wp_query;

     $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

   echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
 ) );
  ?>
    </nav>

    <?php } else { ?>
```

This was working fine until i updated the version of Wordpress to 4 and now each time i click to go to a new page it doesn't redirect, instead just stays on the same page even though the url points to http://jenningsrugs.co.uk/pages/?page_id=2703#038;paged=3

Can help please?

Full code here:

```
   <?php
/*
Template Name: Runners Template
*/

get_header();
?>
<table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_01.jpg" width="57" height="20"></td>
    <td><img src="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_02.jpg" width="886" height="20"></td>
    <td><img src="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_03.jpg" width="57" height="20"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td background="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_04.jpg"><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="57" height="416" /></td>
    <td valign="top" background="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_05.jpg"><table width="886" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="30" height="1" /></td>
          <td><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="826" height="1" /></td>
          <td><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="30" height="1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="30" height="10" /></td>
          <td align="left">
          <div id="content" class="narrowcolumn" role="main">

        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>




        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
        </div>

<h2 class="pagetitle"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[searchandfilter id="2706"]' ); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[searchandfilter id="2706" show="results"]' ); ?>
<a class="reset" href="#" onclick="$('select').each(function() { this.selectedIndex = 0 });">Reset search</a>
    <?php // Display blog posts on any page @ http://m0n.co/l
        $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('cat=24' . '&paged='.$paged);
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class() ?>>
                <h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>


                <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_content() ?>
                </div>

                <br>

        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

        <nav id="nav-posts">
            <?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
        </nav>

        <?php } else { ?>

        <nav id="nav-posts">
            <?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
        </nav>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else :

        if ( is_category() ) { // If this is a category archive
            printf("<h2 class='center'>Sorry, but there aren't any posts in the %s category yet.</h2>", single_cat_title('',false));
        } else if ( is_date() ) { // If this is a date archive
            echo("<h2>Sorry, but there aren't any posts with this date.</h2>");
        } else if ( is_author() ) { // If this is a category archive
            $userdata = get_userdatabylogin(get_query_var('author_name'));
            printf("<h2 class='center'>Sorry, but there aren't any posts by %s yet.</h2>", $userdata->display_name);
        } else {
            echo("<h2 class='center'>No posts found.</h2>");
        }
        get_search_form();

    endif;
?>

    </div>
          </td>
          <td><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="30" height="10" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td background="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_06.jpg"><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="57" height="416" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The format of your URL is bad. IF you check this, it works: http://jenningsrugs.co.uk/pages/?page_id=2703&paged=3

Comment: Thanks. The format of the URL is bad and will be updated to display the page keywords in the future. Do you know where the #038 is coming from in the URL?

Comment: here are the links may be helpful to you https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/commit/22788e505de1dfc47d421af6e7f9b3630efde400 https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/6407

Comment: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/6220

Answer (score 3):

A solution for this issue is using replace.

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$search_for   = array( $big, '#038;' );
$replace_with = array( '%#%', '&' );
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $search_for, $replace_with, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

edit :

```
$search_for   = array( $big, '#038;', '&&' );
$replace_with = array( '%#%', '&', '&' );
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.